# Discord.py roleplay bot not working, doesn't do anything

Tags: python-3.x, conda, chatbot, discord.py

I am making a bot for roleplay,and this bot is for to draw diseases for characters. Bot has to add names of characters send in "postacie-do-losowania" channel to list, delete names from "postacie-do-usunięcia" channel and write list to txt file. It has to read txt file on start too. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this script? Thanks for any help.

That's what I have.
(sorry if my english isn't very good)

````
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

token = "token"
i = 0
client = discord.Client()
characters = []
with open('characters.txt', 'r') as filehandle:
    filecontents = filehandle.readlines()

    for line in filecontents:
        # remove linebreak which is the last character of the string
        character = line[:-1]

        # add item to the list
        characters.append(character)
colors = [0xb06500, 0xe5aa70, 0xd2691e, 0x536878, 0x536878, 0xeeeeee, 0xfaf9d5, 0x654321]
diseases = ["kaszel, kichanie", "kaszel, kichanie, biała wydzielina cieknąca z nosa, lekko podwyższona temperatura", "mo"
        "cny, nieustający ból brzucha", "mocny, nieustający ból brzucha", "mocny, nieustający ból brzucha", "ból od spo"
        "du łap, opuchnięte łapy", "lekki, ale dokuczliwy ból głowy", "lekki, ale dokuczliwy ból brzucha", "lekki, ale "
        "dokuczliwy ból zęba", "ból gardła; można poczuć w nim suchość", "gdzie niegdzie swędzące futro", "gdzie niegdz"
                                                                    "ie swędzące futro, na którym widać kleszcze"]
diseases_zima = ["kaszel, kichanie", "kaszel, kichanie, biała wydzielina cieknąca z nosa, lekko podwyższona temperatura"
    , "kaszel, kichanie, biała wydzielina cieknąca z nosa, lekko podwyższona temperatura", "mocny, nieustający ból brzu"
        "cha", "chrypka, kaszel, ropa z oczu, kichanie, gorączka, zielona wydzielina cieknąca z nosa", "chrypka, kaszel"
        ", ropa z oczu, kichanie, gorączka, zielona wydzielina cieknąca z nosa", "ból od spodu łap, opuchnięte łapy",
            "lekki, ale dokuczliwy ból głowy", "lekki, ale dokuczliwy ból brzucha", "lekki, ale dokuczliwy ból zęba",
        "ból gardła; można poczuć w nim suchość", "kaszel, Kichanie, zimne dreszcze", "kaszel, Kichanie, zimne dreszcz"
                                                                                      "e"]
messages_goodluck = ["Niech klan gwiazdy cię prowadzi.", "Wracaj do zdrowia!", "Modlimy się o ciebie.", "Niech szczęści"
                                                                                                        "e ci sprzyja!"]

discord.AllowedMentions(everyone=True, users=True, roles=True)

print(characters)
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("losowanko..."))
async def on_message(message):
    if str(message.channel) == "postacie-do-losowania":
        characters.append(message.content)
        await message.channel.send('Dodano')
        with open('characters.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
            for listitem in characters:
                filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
    elif str(message.channel) == "postacie-do-usunięcia" and str(message.content) in characters:
        characters.remove(message.content)
        with open('characters.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
            for listitem in characters:
                filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
            await message.channel.send("Usunięto")
    elif str(message.channel) == "postacie-do-usunięcia" and str(message.content) == "all":
        characters.clear()
        await message.channel.send("Usunięto")
    elif str(message.channel) == "losowanie-bot":
        if message.content == "*losowanie":
            diseases_drawn = []
            choiced = []
            loops = random.randint(4, 12)
            tochoice = [item for item in characters]
            diseases_to_draw = diseases
            for i in range(loops):
                random_choice = random.choice(tochoice)
                choiced.append(random_choice)
                tochoice.remove(random_choice)
                random_choice_choroba = random.choice(diseases_to_draw)
                diseases_drawn.append(random_choice_choroba)
            n = 0
            while n < loops:
                goodluck = random.choice(messages_goodluck)
                embed = discord.Embed(title=choiced[n], colour=random.choice(colors), description="zachorował/a, a taki"
                                                                                                  "e są objawy: ")
                embed.add_field(name=diseases_drawn[n], value=goodluck)
                await message.channel.send(content=None, embed=embed)
                n += 1
            await message.channel.send("```KONIEC LOSOWANIA. WIADOMOŚĆ TYLKO NA POTRZEBĘ ODDZIELENIA OD INNYCH LOSOWAŃ.```")
        elif message.content == "*losowanie_zima":
            diseases_drawn = []
            choiced = []
            loops = random.randint(2, 16)
            tochoice = [item for item in characters]
            diseases_to_drawzima = diseases_zima
            for i in range(loops):
                random_choice = random.choice(tochoice)
                choiced.append(random_choice)
                tochoice.remove(random_choice)
                random_choice_choroba = random.choice(diseases_to_drawzima)
                diseases_drawn.append(random_choice_choroba)
            n = 0
            while n < loops:
                goodluck = random.choice(messages_goodluck)
                embed = discord.Embed(title=choiced[n], colour=random.choice(colors), description="zachorował/a, a taki"
                                                                                                  "e są objawy: ")
                embed.add_field(name=diseases_drawn[n], value=goodluck)
                await message.channel.send(content=None, embed=embed)
                n += 1
            await message.channel.send("```KONIEC LOSOWANIA. WIADOMOŚĆ TYLKO NA POTRZEBĘ ODDZIELENIA OD INNYCH LOSOWAŃ.```")
client.run(token)
````

Comment: too much code, please add comments, what part does what, be more brief and dont put your whole code here, also please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The `on_message` event it's not working because you didn't add the decorator

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # ...
```

You should also enable some intents, `on_message` requires `intents.messages`

```py
# Enabling default intents, everything except privileged intents (members and presences)
intents = discord.Intents.default()

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Comment: I'll try! Thanks for help!

Comment: Może czegoś nie zrozumiałem, po nazwie i profilówce widzę, że polak, więc mógłbyś wytłumaczyć po polsku? Jestem jeszcze młody i mój angielski nie jest mocno zaawansowany (sens mniej więcej zrozumiałem, ale prosiłbym o polskie tłumaczenie). Bo jak na razie to mi pokazuje że moduł discord nie ma atrybutu "intents".

Comment: add me on discord for that `kwieeciol#6035`